# adding hyperlink between the label in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display message within the label by code behind.My code do look like as below.

```
lblmsg.Text = "Success: You have added " + pujaname + "  <a href="ShoppingCart.aspx"> to your shopping cart </a> ";
```

Here "pujanme" is extracting from database which is coming correctly and secondly I want to inlcude "shopping cart" text which is hyperlink to other page but I am geting error.I will be pleased if somebody guides me.
Thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this. It is working for me.

```
lblmsg.Text = "Success: You have added " + pujaname +" <a href=\"ShoppingCart.aspx\"> to your shopping cart </a> ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the double quotes in your link (by adding a backslash in front of them):

```
lblmsg.Text = "Success: You have added " + pujaname +
            + "  <a href=\"ShoppingCart.aspx\"> to your shopping cart </a> ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to precede the inner `"` of url with `\`.

```
 lblmsg.Text = "Success: You have added " + pujaname + "  <a href=\"ShoppingCart.aspx\"> to your shopping cart </a> ";
```

Answer (score 0):

If its vb then you can just write it simple like below: Html can be put inline as long as they are in between double quotes:

lblmsg.Text = "Success: You have added " + pujaname + " *your shopping cart* 
"